# Efficiently fill a std::vector: push_back vs operator[]

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose we needed to store a large number of objects of a given type in a std::vector. The number of elements is only known during runtime, but does not change once determined. Is there any noticeable difference in performance between

- initializing the vector to its final size and then directly accessing each element
- creating an empty vector, then filling it with push_back?

  ```
  /* Variant a*/
  std::vector<foo> vector_a;
  for(int i = 0; i < NumOfElems; i++){ // NumOfElems is known
      vector_a.push_back(GetNextElem());
  }

  /* Variant b */
  std::vector<foo> vector_b(NumOfElems);
  for(int i = 0; i < NumOfElems; i++){
      vector_b[i] = GetNextElem();
  }
  ```

I wonder if there's any overhead using *push_back* over directly accessing the elemens that could be avoided when the size is fixed and known.

Thank you.

Comment: I'll place my bet on `vector_b` since `push_back` might have to reallocate the vector several times.

Comment: You should know you aren't reserving, you are preallocating. If default constructing an object and assigning to it is expansive, that'd be a pessimization. [Study the vector API more closely](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It can be used with a variety of types.